# How can to display two inserted text to textview when a button is clicked in android

Tags: android, button, textview

i have tried this code for display one inserted textview. So, how if i want to display two?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    hasil = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);     
}       

public void kirim(View v) {
    EditText chat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    hasil.setText(chat.getText().toString());   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not initiate components like  `(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1 + R.id.editText2);` Please refer first [Android Development](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) Doc.

You can use below code:

```
TextView hasil;
EditText chat1,chat2;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 hasil = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 chat1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 chat2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    }

    public void kirim(View v) {

      hasil.setText(chat1.getText().toString()+" "+chat2.getText().toString());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  hasil = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);   

  }         

public void kirim(View v)   {       
EditText chat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText chat2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
 hasil.setText(chat.getText().toString()+""+chat2.getText().toString());  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Its invalid way to initialize view!*

`EditText chat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1 + R.id.editText2);`

*You have to do@*

```
public void kirim(View v)   {       
editboxchat1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 editboxchat2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
hasil.setText(editboxchat1.getText().toString()+""+editboxchat2.getText().toString()); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

findViewById (int id)

Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle). It just looks through view hierarchy and returns reference to a view with requested viewId.

```
EditText chat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1 + R.id.editText2);

We can not add two views like above. findViewById will just try to find the view.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView hasil;
EditText edit1,edit2;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 hasil = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 edit1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 edit2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
 String _s = edit1.getText().toString();
 String _ss = edit2.getText().toString();
 String _sss = _s + _ss;
}

public void kirim(View v) {

  hasil.setText(_sss);

}
```